# ¿Cambiar color de una celda?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Tengo una tabla en la cual imprimo varios datos, pero quiero que en la celda, estado, al estar en espera sea de un color, y la estar aprobado, de otro.

Intente con jQuery pero de momento no me ha funcionado.

```
<!--
.estado1 {background-color : #ffff99; }
.estado2 {background-color : #00ffff; } --> 
</style>
<table class="table table-responsive">
    <tr class="success">
        <th>No de Deposito</th>
        <th>No de Comprobante</th>
        <th>Monto</th>
        <th>Banco</th>
        <th>Tipo de Transacción</th>
        <th>Fecha de Comprobante</th>
        <th>Detalles</th>
        <th>Observaciones</th>
        <th>Fecha de Solicitud de Autorización</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th>Fecha de Autorización</th>
    </tr>

@foreach($depositos as $deposito)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $deposito->id}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->noboleta}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->monto}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->banco->nombre}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->tipo->tipo}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->fechaboleta}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->detalles}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->observaciones}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->created_at}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->estado->estado}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->updated_at}}</td>
    <td>

    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
<script src=”http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js” type=”text/javascript”></script>
 <script type=”text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('td:contains(“espera”)').addclass('estado1');
   $('td:contains(“aprobado”)').addclass('estado2');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es crear una condición dentro de la misma estructura usando las herramientas que provee **blade**.

Para que te asegures que tus estilos sean prioridad sobre otros podrías usar `!important` o bien podrías usar clases que trae Bootstrap por defecto `.info` o `.danger`

```
<style>
  .estado1 {background-color : #ffff99 !important; }
  .estado2 {background-color : #00ffff !important; }
</style>

<table class="table table-responsive">
    <tr class="success">
        <th>No de Deposito</th>
        <th>No de Comprobante</th>
        <th>Monto</th>
        <th>Banco</th>
        <th>Tipo de Transacción</th>
        <th>Fecha de Comprobante</th>
        <th>Detalles</th>
        <th>Observaciones</th>
        <th>Fecha de Solicitud de Autorización</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th>Fecha de Autorización</th>
    </tr>

@foreach($depositos as $deposito)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $deposito->id}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->noboleta}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->monto}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->banco->nombre}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->tipo->tipo}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->fechaboleta}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->detalles}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->observaciones}}</td>
    <td>{{ $deposito->created_at}}</td>
    @if($deposito->estado->estado == 'espera')
      <td class="estado1">{{ $deposito->estado->estado}}</td>
    @elseif($deposito->estado->estado == 'aprobado')
      <td class="estado2">{{ $deposito->estado->estado}}</td>
    @endif
    <td>{{ $deposito->updated_at}}</td>
    <td>

    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```